# The websites width becomes wider than viewport. How can i remove this?

Tags: html, css

> ## The websites width becomes wider than viewport, so youll be able to scroll "to the side". How can i remove this? I have tried searching
>
> for solutions, but they dont seem to work.  I'd like to keep the
> hamburger navbar where it was, just remove the extra space is creates.
> I think its because theres a shape thats created, so it wont work with
> just

```
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
object-fit: cover;
left:0;
```

as these would ruin the shape. Here is the css and html code:

```
CSS

html { font-size: 18px; }

body {
  color: #e0e4cc;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background: #fa6900;

}
/* x box color */
label .menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;

 
}


/* HOVER EFFECT */
#navs a:hover {
  color: #e71f2d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navs .active {
  color: #e71f2d;
}
/* HOVER EFFECT ^*/

label .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #DAA520;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

label .hamburger:after, label .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #DAA520;
}

label .hamburger:before { top: -10px; }

label .hamburger:after { bottom: -10px; }

label input { display: none; }

/* FOOTER SIZE & COLOR*/
label input:checked + .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200vw rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 200vh rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: 80%;

  
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
  
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
  
}

label input:checked + .menu + ul { opacity: 1; }

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #DAA520;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

HTML

    <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="menu"> <span class="hamburger"></span> </span>
    <ul id="navs">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </ul>
    </label>
```

Comment: I tried setting the menu to be `position: fixed` and that seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding position: fixed; in the .menu class

```css
html { font-size: 18px; }

body {
  color: #e0e4cc;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background: #fa6900;

}
/* x box color */
label .menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;

 
}


/* HOVER EFFECT */
#navs a:hover {
  color: #e71f2d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navs .active {
  color: #e71f2d;
}
/* HOVER EFFECT ^*/

label .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #DAA520;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

label .hamburger:after, label .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #DAA520;
}

label .hamburger:before { top: -10px; }

label .hamburger:after { bottom: -10px; }

label input { display: none; }

/* FOOTER SIZE & COLOR*/
label input:checked + .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200vw rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 200vh rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: 80%;

  
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
  
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
  
}

label input:checked + .menu + ul { opacity: 1; }

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #DAA520;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>  
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="menu"> <span class="hamburger"></span> </span>
    <ul id="navs">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </ul>
  </label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you response.
Yea it did the trick, but now theres a "half circle" is showing in the corner, and the hamburger isnt even in the center of it. Also, how can i make it sticky, so it sticks at the top when i scroll?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. Let me know if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Viewport look this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

it might help